# finding min but zero

Tags: java, arrays, double, min

How can I find the smallest positive (non-zero) number in an array of doubles? For example, if the array contains `0.04`, `0.0001`, and `0.0`, I want to return `0.0001`.

The below function is good, but it will return zero as the min, which is not my interest.

```
static double[] absOfSub = new double[100];
...

private static double compare(double[] ds) {
  double min = absOfSub[0];

  for (double d : ds) {
    min = Math.min(min, d);
  }
  return min;
}
```

How can I make it ignore zeroes?

Comment: Why is it wrong? it seems to me like the lowest  number in the array.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet did you scroll down? isnt 7.719277021974478E-73 smaller than that?

Comment: No no no, the bigger the X in the `E-X`, the lower the number... this is scientific notation...

Comment: @BinyaminSharet ooh my bad math :) ok so your answer is right then :)

Comment: @lonesome Please check my edit and see if it's clearer and asks the right question.

Comment: @AdamLiss yea it looks clearer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check for zero:

```
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for (double d : ds) 
{
    min = (d == 0) ? min : Math.min(min, d);
}
```

Comment: shouldnt it be **Double.MIN_VALUE**?

Comment: Nope. if you start with `Double.MIN_VALUE`, you'll always get it as a result (`Double.MIN_VALUE`) regardless of what your array contains, if you start with `Double.MAX_VALUE`, you'll get the lowest in the array.

Comment: I have looked, see my comment.